# QTooltip for QActions in QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip, qmenu, qaction

I want to be able to show ToolTips for `QMenu` items (`QAction`s). The best I have achieved is to connect the hovered signal of the `QAction` to a `QTooltip` show:

```
connect(action, &QAction::hovered, [=]{
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), text, this);
});
```

The problem is that sometimes the program will position the tooltip below the menu, specially when changing menus.

Is there any way to force the tooltip to show on top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subclass `QMenu` and reimplementing `QMenu::event()` to intercept the `QEvent::ToolTip` event and call `QToolTip::showText` to set the tooltip for the active action :

```
#include <QtGui>

class Menu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Menu(){}
    bool event (QEvent * e)
    {
        const QHelpEvent *helpEvent = static_cast <QHelpEvent *>(e);
         if (helpEvent->type() == QEvent::ToolTip && activeAction() != 0) 
         {
              QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), activeAction()->toolTip());
         } else 
         {
              QToolTip::hideText();
         }
         return QMenu::event(e);
    }
};
```

Now you can use your custom menu like :

```
Menu *menu = new Menu();
menu->setTitle("Test menu");
menuBar()->addMenu(menu);

QAction *action1 =  menu->addAction("First");
action1->setToolTip("First action");

QAction *action2 =  menu->addAction("Second");
action2->setToolTip("Second action");
```

Answer (score 30):

Since Qt 5.1, you can use QMenu's property [`toolTipsVisible`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#toolTipsVisible-prop), which is by default set to `false`.

See the [related Qt suggestion](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13663).